# Gitlab API curl request

Tags: api, curl, get, gitlab

When I'm trying to use GitLab API GET request to get all commits from specific date range and specific branch, I receive only commits from NEXT day after I put since date.

I mean, if I define since date for example - from `2022-12-01T12:17:30.000+02:00` until `2022-12-15T15:01:36.000+01:00`. But, my commits from curl request starting from 2 Dec 2022.

How does to include initial date to response?

```bash
curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/ID/repository/commits"?ref_name=${branch}&since=${since_date}&until=${until_date}" | jq -r '.[] | .committed_date + "\t" + .title'
```

Response which I receive:

```
2022-12-15T15:01:36.000+01:00
2022-12-15T14:39:44.000+02:00
2022-12-14T08:26:43.000+02:00
2022-12-13T20:55:03.000+02:00
2022-12-13T15:51:34.000+01:00
2022-12-13T15:43:26.000+01:00
2022-12-12T16:50:49.000+01:00
2022-12-07T16:38:26.000+01:00
2022-12-05T22:41:04.000+01:00
2022-12-02T09:23:58.000+01:00
```

By the way, I tried to use, but it didn't help me.

```
?first_parent=true
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a pagination problem. Try adding `&per_page=100` to see if there are more commits. I think you can't get more than 100 items in one api call.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination for more info